# What is the angle at which these two curves intersect?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, analytic-geometry

What is the angle at which these two curves intersect?

$$x^2 + y^2 = 12x$$

$$y = ((x-6)^{2})^{1/3}$$

I have a book where I found this problem. It's even solved there but I think there're two mistakes in the solution. So I think the answer given there is not correct.

I solved it myself too. Here is what I got. The curves intersect at two points.

$A(6+3\sqrt{3}, 3)$
$B(6-3\sqrt{3}, 3)$

Is this correct?

Also, I got that the angles of intersection of the two curves are equal at these two points (ignoring the orientation/sign of the angles of course). And I got that the angle is $$\arctan\ {\frac{11}{\sqrt{3}}}$$  Is this correct?

The answer in the book is

$$\arctan\ {\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{7}}$$

but I think this one is not correct.

Comment: For the 2nd point of intersection, you seem to be using $y^3 = (x-6)^2$, which is somewhat different from $y = (x-6)^{2/3}$ (which requires $ x \geq 6$).

Comment: @CalvinLin Sorry. There's no negative base here. I've made a correction in the equation for curve 2.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection points are correct by inspection.

For the angles we need to consider derivatives at that points, that is for point $A$

- $x^2 + y^2 = 12x \implies y=\sqrt{12x-x^2} \implies y'(x)=\frac{6-x}{\sqrt{12x-x^2}}\implies y'(6+3\sqrt 3)=-\sqrt 3$
- $y = (x-6)^{\frac{2}{3}} \implies y'(x)=\frac{2}{3(x-6)^\frac13}\implies  y'(6+3\sqrt 3)=\frac{2\sqrt 3}9$

therefore, using that

$$\arctan{u}+\arctan{v}=\arctan\left(\frac{u+v}{1-uv}\right)$$

we obtain

$$\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{2\sqrt 3}9\right)-\arctan(-\sqrt 3)=$$
$$= \arctan\left(\frac{2\sqrt 3}9\right)+\arctan(\sqrt 3)=\arctan \frac{11}{\sqrt 3}$$

which corresponds to your solution.

Same solution holds also for point $B$ by symmetry.

Comment: So my answer is correct? There's no negative base here. I've made a correction in the equation for curve 2.

Comment: @peter.petrov Yes that's seems perfectly fine to me, for point $B$ angle is the same by symmetry.